# How to classify the developed and emerging market worldwide?

Tags: reference-request, international-economics

I am doing a cross-country research where different countries implement anti-corruption at the different year. I want to examine the impact of the laws in each set of countries (developed and developing). The first country implement the law in 1993 and the last country implement the law in 2016.

I am wondering what index or source i need to use to classify the emerging and developed market in this case. Many thanks and warm regards.

I searched something like that

https://www.msci.com/documents/1296102/1360895/8.5x11inch_MSCI_Country_Classification_Standard_FactSheet.pdf/5b95f2f4-4ced-43a2-92ad-218771a2218c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no set rules for what developed and emerging markets are. Different institutions whether public or private might have different definitions.

This being said you should not just decide arbitrarily about which country you assign developed or emerging status otherwise that would become weak point of your research.

You can either use definitions used by some institution, as long as you can justify it. For example, you could just use [Standard’s & Poor’s methodology](https://eldis.org/organisation/A1847) .

Alternatively, you can develop your own methodology but in that case you should do it in some rigorous manner. That is you explain what characteristics will make country emerging market and which characteristics developed country and how you are going to measure these characteristics where is the cutoff etc.